# Extract a part of a regex name

Tags: javascript

Examples of filenames

1. `FDIP_en-gb-nn_Text_v1_YYYYMMDD_SequenceNumber.txt`
2. `FDIP_fr-fr-nn_Text_v1_YYYYMMDD_SequenceNumber.txt`
3. `FDIP_de-de-nn_Text_v1_YYYYMMDD_SequenceNumber.txt`

REGEX is `FDIP_([a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}-[a-z]{2})_Text_v1_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{14}.txt`

The only part I need is the translation code which is 'en-gb', 'fr-fr' , 'de-de.

How do I extract just that part of the filename?

Comment: try using `group name` to extract that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find indices of groups in JavaScript regular expressions match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985594/how-to-find-indices-of-groups-in-javascript-regular-expressions-match)

Comment: I'm assuming you're running it with case-insensitive (otherwise the `[A-Z]{2}` would fail your examples).  In which case, just move the bracket forward (so it's `([a-z{2}-[A-Z]{2})` and then use the first group returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, you should:

- Fix your regex:

```regex
FDIP_([a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}-[a-z]{2})_Text_v1_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{14}.txt
// to
FDIP_([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})-[a-z]{2}_Text_v1_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{14}.txt
```

- Use get value from `first group` by using `regex.exec` function

```js
const fileNames = [
'FDIP_en-gb-nn_Text_v1_20190101_12345678901234.txt',
'FDIP_fr-fr-nn_Text_v1_20200202_12345678901234.txt',
'FDIP_de-de-nn_Text_v1_20180808_12345678901234.txt']

const cultureNames = fileNames.map(name => {
  const matched = /FDIP_([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})-[a-z]{2}_Text_v1_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{14}.txt/.exec(name)
  
  return matched && matched[1]
})

console.log(cultureNames)
```

Comment: It's better to explain exactly what you've changed.. otherwise you're expecting people to search through a long regex looking for tiny changes (in this case moving a single `)` character)

Answer (score 1):

Modified the regex little bit to match the numbers and text. You can play around [here](https://regexr.com/4oo81)

Explanation 
to capture a group you need to wrap the regex into `()` this will capture as a group.

to do the named capturing you can `(?<name_of_group>)` and then you can access by name.

Here goes the matching process.

`[a-z]{2}` match 2 char from `a-z`

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` match any char of `a-z or A-Z or 0-9`

`g` means global flag i.e. match all.

`i` means  ignore case.

```js
var r = /FDIP_([a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2})-[a-z]{2}_Text_v1_[0-9A-Z]{8}_[A-Z0-9]{14}.txt/gi;

let t = 'FDIP_en-gb-nn_Text_v1_YYYYMMDD_SequenceNumber.txt';

let dd = r.exec(t);


console.log(dd[1]);
```

This is example of group capturing

See the name in the `regex` and the object destructing name is matching.

```js
const { groups: { language } } = /FDIP_(?<language>[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2})-[a-z]{2}_Text_v1_[0-9A-Z]{8}_[A-Z0-9]{14}.txt/gi.exec('FDIP_en-gb-nn_Text_v1_YYYYMMDD_SequenceNumber.txt');

console.log(language);
```

Comment: It's better to explain exactly what you've changed.. otherwise you're expecting people to search through a long regex looking for tiny changes (in this case moving a single `)` character)

Comment: @freefaller Thanks for pointing out. I've added the explanation. Let me know if missing something.

Comment: thank you for the feedback what if there is many types of filenames that will be loaded as stated do i create an array where r is

Comment: You can use multi line flag `m` in the regex if you want to match multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Change `FDIP_([a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}-[a-z]{2})_Text_v1_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{14}.txt`

to

```js
let pattern = /FDIP_([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})-[a-z]{2}_Text_v1_[\w]{8}_[\w]{14}.txt/;

var str = 'FDIP_en-gb-nn_Text_v1_YYYYMMDD_SequenceNumber.txt';
console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]);
```