# Trying to find indices of all regex matches, but some being left out

Tags: javascript, regex, string, indexing

I want to find the index of every vowel after the first "e" in a string.

Since you can't get the index of the capture group directly from `RegExp.exec(sInput)`, [but you can get the length of a capture group containing everything in front of the *actual* capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985594/how-to-find-indices-of-groups-in-javascript-regular-expressions-match), the regex I'm using to do this is `/(.*?e.*?)(a|e|i|o|u)(.*)/`.

So the setup is basically like this:

```js
let re = /(.*?e.*?)(a|e|i|o|u)(.*)/g;
let sInput = "lorem ipsum";

let tMatches = [];
let tMatchIndices = [];
let iPrevIndex = 0;

while (result = re.exec(sInput)) {
    /*  result[0]: full match
        result[1]: match for 1st capture group (.*?e.*?)
        result[2]: match for 2nd capture group (a|e|i|o|u)
        result[3]: match for 3rd capture group (.*)
    */
    let index = result[1].length + iPrevIndex;
    let sMatch = result[2];
    tMatchIndices.push(index);
    tMatches[index] = sMatch;
    iPrevIndex = index + sMatch.length;
    re.lastIndex = iPrevIndex;
}

for (i = 0; i < tMatches.length; i++) {
  let index = tMatchIndices[i];
    console.log(tMatches[index] + " at index "+index);
}
```

The issue is for the input string "lorem ipsum", I need the indices for both the "i" and the "u"... and it's only giving me the index for "i".

I know *why* it's doing this - advancing the search index past the first match cuts out the "e" that's supposed to trigger the next match. What I'm stuck on is how to fix it. I can't just simply *not* advance the search index, or it would never move past the first match anyway.

I've thought about simply *deleting* each match from the search string as I go along, but then that shifts the index of every character after it to the left, so the indices I would collect wouldn't even be accurate for the original, untruncated string.

What do?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to keep things simple would be to strip off the leading substring up to, and including, the first `e`.  Then, just iterate the remaining string one character at a time, checking for vowels along the way.

```js
sInput = "lorem ipsum";
nInput = sInput.replace(/^.*?(?:e|$)/, "");
var index = sInput.length - nInput.length;
var indices = [];
var counter = 0;
for (var i=0; i < nInput.length; i++) {
    if (/[aeiou]/.test(nInput.charAt(i))) {
        indices[counter++] = i + index;
    }
}

console.log(indices);
```

Regarding the output:

```
01234567890
lorem ipsum
      ^  ^  [6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a positive lookbehind:

```js
'lorem ipsum'.replace(/(?<=e.*)[aiueo]/g, function(m, offset) {
  console.log(m + ' ==> ' + offset)
});
```

Output:

```
i ==> 6
u ==> 9
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=e.*)` - positive lookbehind for character `e`
- `[aiueo]` - scan for a vowel
- use the `g` flag to repeat
- in the replace function you can reference the offset

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`String.prototype.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#browser_compatibility), which returns an iterator of matches, each being an array with the `index` property:

```js
[...str.matchAll(/(?<=^.*?e.*?)[aeiou]/gis)].map(m => m.index);
```

Demo:

```js
const findIndices = str => {
  const regex = /(?<=^.*?e.*?)[aeiou]/gis;
  return [...str.matchAll(regex)].map(m => m.index);
}

console.log(findIndices('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'));
```

```css
.as-console-row-code { white-space: normal !important; }
```